# Codeigniter + jquery: specify MIME type text/xml in ajax request response

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax, codeigniter

I am making an ajax request from a jquery script to one of my ajax controllers in codeigniter.  This process works fine when using data type json.  However, when I want to send xml back from the server, the jquery documentation says that the server must specify a MIME type of text/xml.  How do I do this with codeigniter.
My ajax call looks like this:

```
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: siteUrl + "index.php/ajax_controller/test",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: testSuccess
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a content type header using the following code.  You could put it at the top of your controller method in CI:

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
```

It must be before any output starts, so use it before you call your first `$this->load->view()`.